# What part of speech is "her" and "drive" in "I watched her drive."?

Tags: verbs, parts-of-speech, parsing, direct-objects

Would "her" be the direct object of the transitive verb, "watched"? Or would the verb phrase itself act as the direct object?

Comment: Yes, "her" is the object of "watched". "Watch" is a catenative verb, and "drive" is a subordinate clause functioning as its catenative complement. The intervening noun phrase, "her", is the syntactic object of "watched" and the semantic (_understood_) subject of the subordinate clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I watched her drive".

*drive* is a bare infinitive used after the verb of perception "watch" with the direct object *her*

> Using the bare infinitive [...]
> 2. **The bare infinitive is also used after common verbs of perception with a direct object** (watch, hear, feel), and common verbs of
> permission or causation (make, have, let).
>
> **I felt it move!**

[Bare infinitive](https://www.kaplaninternational.com/blog/learning-languages/eng/full-infinitive-and-bare-infinitive-grammar-differences#:%7E:text=The%20bare%20infinitive%20is%20also,the%20dog%20finish%20my%20food.)

> After verbs of perception (see, watch, hear, listen, feel, smell,
> notice, observe etc.), the infinitive expresses a completed action:
>
> **I felt the ground shake** once. (I felt it as the ground shook once.)

[bare infinitive after a verb of perception with direct object](https://www.grammaring.com/see-watch-hear-listen-feel-smell-notice-observe-object-bare-infinitive)